# parse json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'contact',
      type: 'post',
      asynch: 'false', 
      dataType: 'json' ,
      data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + $("#recaptcha_challenge_field").val() + 
            "&recaptcha_response_field=" + $("#recaptcha_response_field").val() ,           
      success: function(data) {             
        alert(data);        
        return;
      }   
    });
```

json reponse looks like this

```
{"the_result":"false"}
```

but alert(data) gives [object,object]

Comment: Do you mean it gives `[object Object]` instead of `[object,object]`?

Answer (score 11):

`alert(data.the_result)` will display `false` in your example, or whatever the value of `the_result` is generally.

Answer (score 4):

The response that you are getting is an Object.
To display the data, you need to use:

```
alert(data.the_result);
```

or

```
alert(data["the_result"]);
```

If you just want the whole JSON string then just change the dataType to "text".

Answer (score 0):

I think your success function should look like this:

```
function(data){
  alert(data.the_result);
  return;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

try this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

then you'll be able to see that data as you want to.

Comment: Always painful to watch.  Flip your post to CW to stem the downvote penalties.

Comment: Sorry I'm sorta new here, what's CW? And why is mine so negative if it was accepted? lawl